# Creating a dynamic alias, is it possible?

Tags: linux, alias, zsh

I'm creating a library in the C language and have separate folders for each header/source file.  I recently had the need to go into many of the folders and change some code in both the .c and .h files.  So I'm frequently using the commands:

```
nano <some-detailed-filename.c>
nano <some-detailed-filename.h>
```

I wanted to look at creating an alias like the following:

```
alias nanc="nano $(ls ./*.c)"
alias nanh="nano $(ls ./*.h)"
```

The idea being that it will open whatever .c/.h files in the current directory.  But when I add these lines to my .zshrc file, I get the following as the aliases:

```
# alias nanc
nanc='nano ./xh.c       ./yp.c'
# alias nanh
nanh='nano ./xh.h       ./yp.h'
```

This is not desired, as the files nano tries to open are only located in my home/login directory.

How can I go about creating this alias so that it uses the current directory I'm in when I issue the command?  I'm not having much luck with my searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use double-quotes in the assignment; use single-quotes.  If you use double-quotes, the value is substituted immediately.

By the way, there is another problem with your alias: the ls command will expand any wildcards which happen to be directory names (it is perfectly legal for a directory to have a name ending with ".c").  To guard against extra-odd results from that, you might want to use the "-d" option, e.g.,

```
alias nanc='nano $(ls -d ./*.c)'
```

However, even the `ls` is redundant.  This works for me:

```
alias nanc='nano *.c'
```

Comment: Ty for your answer.  I'm not worried about hidden files in my case as this alias will only be used when in a directory that I have created that only contains one .c/.h file each.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can create a function and then an alias to that function. In the function one condiction to detect what you want. Even a function with one short name. Find out how to create functions with arguments and then you could to something like 'nan -c' or 'nan -h'.  The bash option getopt give you this possibility.